# Numpy ValueError: shapes not aligned

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, numpy-ndarray

Super simple question here, I am getting this error:

```
shapes (30,) and (1,30) not aligned: 30 (dim 0) != 1 (dim 0)
```

How would I easily refactor the second array to be the same as the first array, or vice versa?

Example:

```
x output is: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]\
y output is: [[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]

x shape is (30,)
y shape is (1,30)
```

Anything helps.

I could use a for loop but that seems so counterintuitive, just looking for a better method.

Thanks

Comment: You don't show what code produces this error, but my guess is `np.dot` of `np.matul/@`.    Read the relevant docs to learn what mix of shapes are allowed.  Do you understand why the two arguments have those shapes?  And what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
y = y.reshape(-1)
```

or

```
y = np.squeeze(y)
```